# Stochastic processes and product $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X_t)_{ t \geq 0 }$ be a family of $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued random variables on a probability space $( \Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. Consider the following statement:

> For  $0 \leq t_1 < t_2 < \ldots < t_n$ $$P( X_{t_1} \in B_1, \ldots, X_{t_n} \in B_n), \quad B_1, \ldots, B_n \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d),$$ determines a probability measure on $\mathcal{B}((\mathbb{R}^d)^n)$.

How exactly should one understand $\mathcal{B}((\mathbb{R}^d)^n)$?

1. Is $(\mathbb{R}^d)^n = \underbrace{ \mathbb{R}^d \times \ldots \times\mathbb{R}^d}_{ n \ \text{times}}$?
2. If so, is $\mathcal{B}((\mathbb{R}^d)^n)$ the Borel sigma-algebra generated by the open subsets of $(\mathbb{R}^d)^n$, where an open set is understood with respect to the metric induced by any matrix norm?
3. Is $\mathcal{B}((\mathbb{R}^d)^n)$ the same as the $n$-fold product $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ with itself?
4. Is there any ambiguity if we instead write $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{d \times n})$?
5. Is there a need to specify whether the elements of $\mathbb{R}^d$ are column vectors or row vectors?

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, no, no

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ and $Y$ are separable metric spaces (or more generally  second countable topological spaces) then the Borel sigma algebra of $X \times Y$ with its product topology is same as the product of the Borel sigma algebras of $X$ and $Y$. By repeated application of this basic fact you can see that there is only one 'natural' sigma algebra on $(\mathbb R^{d})^{n}$.